# How to get scenario outline value in cucumber ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automation-testing

I would like to get the value of scenario outline examples to have meaningful logs

I already succeed to get scenario name for logs, but I don't have to get scenario outline examples values got error

```
undefined method `scenario_outline' for #<Cucumber::Core::Test::Case:
```

here's the before hook code, Can someone help me resolve this?

```
 Before do |scenario|
  if scenario.respond_to?(:scenario_outline) && scenario.scenario_outline
    message = "Running example: #{scenario.scenario_outline.name} - #{scenario.name}"
  else
    message = "Running scenario: #{scenario.name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: do you got any solution for this?